Updating repositories in build.gradle for NativeScript builds
I have an Android application built using @nativescript/core:8.1.3.
I need to download the private android libraries from a private nexus registry.
It seems like after doing ns build android, in the platforms > android > build.gradle, the default repositories are being injected:
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

I have tried to add my private repository in App_Resources > Android > build.gradle as per below:
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'http://127.0.0.1:8081/repository/maven-releases/' }
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'http://127.0.0.1:8081/repository/maven-releases/' }
    }
}

but only the default repositories are being included in the platforms > android > build.gradle.
Ideally I only use my private registry to download any dependencies.
Can this be achieved in NativeScript?
